# CSS div will not expand with content but gives scrollbars instead?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, expand

What is wrong here?

There is just no way I can get the div (the gray area behind the video) to expand with the content... I get scrollbars instead? 
Please help Thanks, Marcus

Try scrolling over the video gray box area. It's the grey area 'main' that I want to expand instead of scrollbars showing.

http://bestofyoutube.com/go/cssprob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the height of your videoarea, the reason the scrollbars are showing up is because the vote area is pushing it down due to the floating. That blank space on top is exactly how much extra scroll area you're getting.

Comment: OH MAN. YOU'RE A STAR.. I have spent six hours trying to solve that problem. Thanks a million

Comment: @MarcusSilverman - Would still suggest fixing your markup, you're going to have other problems with invalid markup.

Comment: Thanks Mystere. I will try and do that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters.. you have invalid markup.

Invalid markup is the #1 reason for things acting strangely.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.peekpod.com%2Fminnie&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

However, the reason you have scrollbars is that you're using `overflow: auto`, if you don't want them then use `overflow: none;`

However, when using `overflow: none;` things are even more messed up do to all your floats.

Comment: Thanks, I see I have a lot to take care of. But some of the markup errors are for code I have directly taken from Facebook i.e. 'like button code'. Is this code incorrect?

Comment: @MarcusSilverman - Well, take out the facebook code for now and fix your errors.  Then add the facebook code back in and see what the problems are there.